# Is there a simple Bugzilla/Trac client for use by non software folks?

Tags: windows, trac, bugzilla

I'm aware this isn't exactly a programming question, but it directly impacts our developers and the code we're assigned to write.  If there's another SO-like forum where this could be better posted, please let me know and I'll take the question down from here & post it there.

Our work environment is a couple of developers creating (20-30%) and maintaining (lion's share) legacy software for factory production floor and test workers to use to calibrate or test the equipment the company sells.  We've implemented a very simple Google form based bug reporting page, but we're already running into problems of scale (approx 40:1 them:us and lots of old-old buggy software that we didn't write).  The company has tried using Bugzilla before my arrival with little success, the factory folks were apparently intimidated by it and wouldn't use it.  However, they seem to like the simple Google form and the wizard-like steps to file a bug or request a feature.  We're currently manually cutting & pasting their bug/feature requests from the Google form spreadsheet into Trac, and manually tracking the bugs/feature requests on a white board with magnetic bug cards.  We're only a few weeks into this system and it's already showing it fragility and lack of scalability.

Ideally we'd have a Windows >= XP web or desktop client that would provide:

- Simplified bug reporting, a Wizard like approach seems to work well
- Customizable for our software packages (like drop downs for each)
- Bugzilla or Trac integration
- Standard bug tracking features developers and management can use

I've found the winners of the "[Make Bugzilla Pretty](http://bugzillaupdate.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/winner-of-the-make-bugzilla-pretty-contest/)" contest, but coming from a pure software house where we just used straight Bugzilla out of the box, I'm unclear on how to configure and install these skins.  Obviously I can figure this out but don't want to go down that path if it's not going to solve our basic problem which is non-technical people reporting bugs.

[TaskCompiler](http://www.pluginedge.com/taskcompiler), found on the [Bugzilla wiki site](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons#Desktop_Clients) seemed like a candidate because it talks to both Bugzilla & Trac, but their sales page is offline and the site hasn't been updated since 2012 and I'm unsure as to their viability.

I'm certain we're not the first production facility to run into problems like this, I'm looking for recommendations to help solve both our scalability as well as-ease-of-use problem.

Another thought that occurs to me is a GAS script to push our current Google forms based bug reports into Trac or Bugzilla.

**Edit:**  The decision between Bugzilla/Trac seems to have been made for us.  I'm exploring options for using Trac [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024073/create-trac-ticket-from-google-form-gas-script) if you want to follow along.

Comment: Also have a look at http://bloodhound.apache.org/ that wants to be user-friendly as one of the main aims. It's built on top of Trac.